# How to send event reminder sms from sql server via sms only?

Tags: sql-server

I want to add the ability to send reminders to people via email and SMS for specific events that they have signed up for on a web application that I am building. The email part is not difficult, but I am wondering where to find a good solution for sending SMS messages and very important is the messages will come from sql server not from front end.
Has anyone implemented something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's really should by done on a client side, SQL Server has other to do than send sms

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Clickatell](https://www.clickatell.com/), unless you have plans to use a different SMS Gateway, if you choose to use [Clickatell](https://www.clickatell.com/), then you should check this out: [Ways to Connect Clickatell with SQL Server](https://zapier.com/zapbook/clickatell/sql-server/)